# copia de cadena a otra, (acción erronea) desbordamiento

Tags: c, linux

Hola qué tal a todos necesito saber porfavor por qué está pasando esto, el problema es el siguiente: dado dos cadenas averiguar si pertenecen al alfabeto1, se llena también el alfabeto2 pero por el momento no nos interesa. Bien de acuerdo a mi lógica así es como lo hice, pero el problema está cuado se copian las cadenas letra por letra al ***char aux1[TAM2]***, se supone que la cadena **aux1[TAM2]**, se llena correctamente porque hice varias pruebas y si imprime todo dentro del ***for*** anidado, pero al momento que se termina las instrucciones del for anidado, quiero averiguar la longitud de mi cadena ***aux1*** , para eso uso un while buscando el caracter nulo, pero vaya sorpresa me dice que es 19 porque imprimo mi iterador **i** y también contiene basura, entonces nose lo que esta pasando, estoy usando linux y compilo de la siguiente manera, ya que de no hacerlo así me sale un error de ***stack smashing detected***, y pues ya no hace nada mi programa por eso compilo de la siguiete forma:

---

> gcc -fno-stack-protector Alfabetos1.c

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM1 3
#define TAM2 6


int main(){
char alfa1[TAM1];
char alfa2[TAM1];
char w1[TAM1];
char w2[TAM1];
char aux1[TAM2];
//char aux2[TAM];
//char aux3[TAM];
int i=0,j=0,k=0;

for(i=0;i<=TAM1-1;i++)
{
    printf("Ingrese el alfabeto_1: ");
    scanf("%c",&alfa1[i]);
    getchar();
}
printf("\n");
for(j=0;j<=TAM1-1;j++)
{
    printf("Ingrese el alfabeto_2: ");
    scanf("%c",&alfa2[j]);
    getchar();
}
printf("\n");

i=0; j=0;
for(i=0;i<=TAM1-1;i++)
{
    printf("Ingrese una cadena W1: ");
    scanf("%c",&w1[i]);
    getchar();
}

printf("\n");
for(j=0;j<=TAM1-1;j++)
{
    printf("Ingrese una cadena W2: ");
    scanf("%c",&w2[j]);
    getchar();
}


i=0; j=0; k=0; 
for(i=0;i<=TAM1-1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=TAM1-1;j++)
    {   
        if(w1[j]==alfa1[i] && w2[j]==alfa1[i])
        {
            aux1[k]=w1[j];
            //printf("%c\n",aux1[k]);
            aux1[k+1]=w2[j];
            //printf("%c\n",aux1[k]);
            k++;
        }
        else if(w1[j]==alfa1[i])
        {
            aux1[k]=w2[i];
            //printf("\n%c",aux1[k]);
            k++;
        }
        else if(w2[j]==alfa1[i])
        {
            aux1[k]=w2[j];
            //printf("\n%c\n",aux1[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
printf("\n");
//longitud de cadena
i=0;
while(aux1[i]!='\0'){
    //printf("\n%c",aux1[i]);
    i++;
}
//impresion de prueba
printf("%d",i);
if(i==TAM2-1)
{
    printf("\nLa cadena pertence al alfabeto");
}
else
{
    printf("La cadena no pertence al alfabeto");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

en ningún momento añades a aux1 el carácter cero del final que luego buscas, con lo que es inevitable que no lo encuentres donde esperas. El while buscará en memoria hasta encontrar un 0, y lo encuentra fuera de tu aux1, osea, en memoria que no es tuya, con lo que si no te da una excepción has tenido suerte. Prueba a hacer un `memset( aux1, 0, TAM2)` antes de empezar a rellenar aux1 y lo que no rellenes después serán todo ceros.

Comment: Sigo teniendo el mismo error...

Comment: Pues lo debes estar haciendo mal porque he copiado tu código, he añadido el memset justo antes de entrar en los dos for anidados y funciona perfectamente. Cuando llega al while, se para donde debe. Hay otra cosa que no me cuadra mucho. Dentro de los dos for anidados, cuando se cumple la condición del if inicial, añades a aux1 dos elementos, uno en la posición k y otro en la k+1, pero luego solo incrementas la k en una posición con k++. Te recomiendo que depures y vayas viendo paso a paso qué valores van tomando las variables.

Comment: ok está bien, solo una última cosa porfvor, rellena el alfabeto1 con a,b,c y el alfabeto2 con d,e,f y para w1 = c,b,a y w2 = a,c,b claro sin las comas la separación es cada enter que das, se supone que w1 y w2 estan en el alfabeto1 y de acuerdo a las condiciones que puse, pues copio todo w1 y w2 a aux y ya cuando sasco la longitud de aux pues tiene que tener todas las letras de w2  y w2 pero me sale la longitud de 19 a veces de 3, no lo mencione pero tengo que comparar que w1 y w2 estén dentro del alfabeto1 eso es todo...

Comment: Pues tendrás que depurar paso a paso y ver cuantas veces y en qué condición se va rellenando aux1 porque está claro que no hace lo que esperas que haga. No lo termino de entender, pero no hay nada mejor que ir paso a paso ejecutando y viendo cómo quedan las variables y comparar lo que crees que debería hacer. Seguro que lo descubres en un momento. Suerte.